# Complement of the Unknot in the Solid Sphere $S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm trying to visualize the complement of the unknot embedded in $S^3$ but what I visualize isn't what I know the answer to be.  Let $K$ be the unknot (a circle), here is what I've been told the answer is, $$S^3\setminus K\text{ is } S^1\times D^2$$ where $S^1\times D^2$ is the solid torus.  But my intuition tells me that $S^1\times D^2$ should be $S^3\setminus S^2$.  I'm certain I'm thinking about this the wrong way so I was hoping someone could explain to me where I've gone wrong.

Edit:  Oh wait, in $S^3$ a circle in homotopic to a point .... did I answer my own question?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^3$- a straight line looks like?

Comment: @John hughes:  Yes, I should have put $D^2$ and I've edited my question to reflect that.  Sorry, silly mistake.

Comment: You did not answer your question. The fact that a circle is null-homotopic does not tell you anything. Also, the complement of $S^2$ is disconnected.

Comment: Think of $S^3$ as being the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then if you remove the $z$-axis (which is an unknot under the compactification), you are left with the solid torus which is 'around' the axis that has been removed.

Comment: @DanRust:  Ahh, that clears it up.  thanks!